# How do i interrupt the loop of a socket

Tags: java, sockets, while-loop

So my program has clients that are entering tasks and they can see each other tasks but i want the server to close when all the clients are shutdown by a command and i don't want to look for more clients after the last one closes.
What i have tried is counting the number of clients that entered and when there is none, the problem is that the server tries to accept new clients and does't check the condition can any one help me?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4242);

            while (acceptNewClients) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                countClient++;
                System.out.println(countClient);
                ThreadedServer clientThread = new ThreadedServer(clientSocket);
                new Thread(clientThread).start();
                if (countClient == 0) {
                    flipAcceptNewClients();
                }
            }

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Set a [timeout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout(int)) on the ServerSocket, maybe after 1 or 2 seconds. When the timeout exception is raised, check and see if you want to `accept()` again or exit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shut down the server, call `System.exit(0);` to do so.

interrupting the thread that is blocking on `serverSocket.accept()` may or may not work; depends on the OS and JVM, hence, that's not a great way to do this.

Comment: I'm not interrupting the thread because that condition is only true when all threads are dead.
And the system.exit(0); would do the same as that if statement and the problem would remain as it still gets stuck in the accept method.

Comment: It would not. System.exit will exit the VM, even if a thread is currently blocking on .accept().

Comment: where would i put the System.exit(0);

Comment: At any point in time when you decide it's time to exit. Thus, in the 'okay this connection is done' part of the code: if the # of open connections (maintain a counter) is 0, sysexit.